# str.slice return empty string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to filter out specific words from big string.

First I use `str.mactch` to filter it out.

Now I need to remove first 7 characters from filtered results. But I keep receiving empty string as a result of `str.slice`.

```js
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("SomeURL", fetchArgs);
var response2 = response.getContentText();
var response3 = response2.match("key.......[0-9]{2,10}");
Logger.log(response3);  
var response4 = response3.slice(5,7);
Logger.log(response4);
}
```

Comment: String.match(...) gives you an array of matched strings, not a string. Try to retrieve the first matched result before attempting to slice it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `String.Join` Method. After this `slice` works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("someURL", fetchArgs);
var response2 = response.getContentText();
var response3 = response2.match(/parent":{"id":"[0-9]{2,10}","key":"NEN-[0-9]{2,10}/g);
Logger.log(response3);
var response4 = response3.join();
Logger.log(response4);
var response5 = response4.slice (30);
Logger.log(response5);
}
```